# 438 object doesn't support this property or method vba

Tags: vba, excel

Below is my code. All of the code works, but I get error 438 object doesn't support this property or method vba in this line. i.offset(-7,-8).paste

```
Sub insert_6_rows()
Dim rActive As Range
Dim wb As Workbook

Set rActive = ActiveCell

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim f As Range
Set f = Sheets("Format").Range("A1:J6")
Dim FindST As Range
Set FindST = Sheets("Driver").Range("I:I").Find(What:="Subtotal", LookIn:=xlValues)
FindST.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Resize(6).Insert
f.Copy
Dim i As Range
Set i = Sheets("Driver").Range("I:I").Find(What:="Subtotal", LookIn:=xlValues)
i.Offset(-7, -8).Paste
rActive.Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I moved f.copy down 3 lines just before i.Offset(-7, -8).PasteSpecial. It works now

Answer (score 0):

Use the Destination argument of a [Range.Copy method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-copy-method-excel).

```
Sub insert_6_rows()

    Dim rActive As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set rActive = ActiveCell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim f As Range, FindST As Range, i As Range

    Set f = workSheets("Format").Range("A1:J6")
    Set FindST = workSheets("Driver").Range("I:I").Find(What:="Subtotal", LookIn:=xlValues)

    FindST.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Resize(6).Insert

    f.Copy Destination:=workSheets("Driver").cells(FindST.row-1, "A")

    rActive.select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It was overwriting my Total i have under the range. I changed -1 to -7, now it's pasting in desired range, but column J does not appear to shift down

Answer (score 0):

1. Use meaningful variable names! Everyone would think of `i` is a simple counter. Eg. better name it `FoundCell`.
2. If nothing is found then you cannot `.Offset` from "nothing", that's why it fails. So you will need to test if something was found.

I suggest:

```
Dim FoundCell As Range
Set FoundCell = Sheets("Driver").Range("I:I").Find(What:="Subtotal", LookIn:=xlValues)

'check if something was found
If FoundCell is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Subtotal not found in column I"
    Exit Sub
End If

'check if found cell.row is at least 7 rows so we can offset -7
If FoundCell.Row <= 7 Then
    MsgBox "Cannot offset -7 rows because found cell is less then 7 rows from top"
    Exit Sub
End If

SourceRange.Copy
FoundCell.Offset(-7, -8).Paste
```

Comment: your code helped me find the issue. Now I first look for  FoundCell then copy and pastespecial. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change Paste to PasteSpecial

```
i.Offset(-7, -8).PasteSpecial
```